# Comment on a suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, editing

I had to reject an edit for an answer today, since it was erroneous. However I wanted to comment on the edit and explain why I rejected it, and found no designated place to do that.

The reason I chose from the existing options is that the edit does not improve the answer (which is the closest thing), but there was no place to add a free-text explanation, nor anywhere to add a comment.

Am I missing something?

I ended up commenting on my original answer in hope that the person who suggested the edit will see my explanation.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It happens all the time. You can always roll back edits or re-edit. Leaving a comment seems like the right thing to do.